# Styling of ready-made components

Tags: android, mapbox

Is it possible to change the styles (colors, fonts, arrangement of elements) in ready-made components?

In my case it is the `SearchBottomSheetView` component from **[Mapbox Search Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/search/guides/)**.

I can't find a direct method for modifying the appearance. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

There is similar request in the search android repository. Looks like they have added some customisation.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-search-android-examples/issues/18